# Java Soket cannot send multicast packet on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, sockets, raspberry-pi, multicastsocket

I try to run this code in Raspberry Pi. The socket can receive data from the multicast group, however, it shows the following error when it tries to send data:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java  Protocol
java.net.MulticastSocket@647e05
java.io.IOException: Cannot assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at Protocol.getSensorData(Protocol.java:201)
    at Protocol.main(Protocol.java:305)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Protocol {

    private MulticastSocket socket = null;
    private MulticastSocket socket_switchPanel = null;
    String MULTICAST_ADDRESS = "";
    int port = -1;

    public Protocol(String NIC, boolean isByIP, String multcastAddress, int port) {
        this.MULTICAST_ADDRESS = multcastAddress;
        this.port = port;
        try {
            InetAddress dstAddr = InetAddress.getByName(MULTICAST_ADDRESS);
            socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
            InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(MULTICAST_ADDRESS, port);

            NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByName(NIC);
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);
            socket.joinGroup(socketAddress, ni);
            System.out.println(ni);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void close_socket() {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }

    public Integer getSensorData() {

        byte[] msg = new byte[]{
                (byte) 0xAB, 0x04, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xCD, 0x00, (byte) 0x01};
        try {
            // get the IP address
            InetAddress dstAddr = InetAddress.getByName(MULTICAST_ADDRESS);

            final DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(msg, msg.length, dstAddr, port);
            socket.send(out);
            // receive data until timeout or stop prematurely on users' request
            try {
                // process multi cast response(s)
                final byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[30];
                final DatagramPacket in = new DatagramPacket(inputBuffer, inputBuffer.length);
                socket.setSoTimeout(500);
                socket.receive(in);
                byte[] data = in.getData();
                return 1;

            } catch (Exception ste) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        tring NIC, boolean isByIP, String multcastAddress, int port
        Protocol dc = new Protocol("wlan0",
                false,
                "ff12:00:00:00:4479:00:00:00",
                50000);
        int ab = dc.getSensorData();
        System.out.println(ab);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. You have to disable other interface. For example, if you are using WIFI to send multicast message. You can disable eth0 by using
`ifconfig eth0 down`. Note that after the PI reboots, the eth0 goes live again.

Answer (score 0):

Your java may be picking up the IP V4 instead of IP V6 (like your multicast address seems to point to). Try starting it with

-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true

Usually this happens with java preferring v6 over v4, but you might have a special case here. Alternatively, you're just using an invalid multicast address (looking at https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml#ipv6-scope it doesn't appear that addresses starting with `ff12` are valid for ipv6 multicast addresses).

Comment: I tried to use IPV6 setting. It does not work. This address is correct and it is our intern server address. I can run the above code in Windows machine. But not sure why it does not work in Pi. Do you have any idea?